# style not working when element created using PHP's "echo' '"

Tags: php, css

I use PHP code to insert some elements in another PHP file, when the elements were originally created inside the calling PHP file style worked just fine, but when i replaced the code with an 'include(somephpfile.php)', elements were added the way i wanted them to but style didnt apply.

style doesn't apply to elements created this way:

```
echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="wow fadeInLeft animated portfolio-item" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="0ms" style="box-shadow: 0px 10px 12px grey; width:80%">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="booksCovers/';
    $queryImage = "SELECT cover from books where bookno = '$temp';";
    $resultsImage = mysqli_query($db, $queryImage);
    $imagesrc = mysqli_fetch_array($resultsImage);
    echo $imagesrc[0];
    echo '" class="img-responsive" alt="this is a title" style="width : 450px ; height :320px; " />
            <div class="mybooks-overlay">
              <div class="desc">
                <div class="description">';
    $query2 = "SELECT description FROM books WHERE bookno = '$temp';";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query2);
    $book = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
    echo $book[0];
    echo '
                </div>
                <a class="details" target="_blank " href=" #">Learn More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <figcaption>



            <button class="myButtone">
              <div class="insider"> </div>
              20. 00$
            </button>


            <div class="heart"></div>

          </figcaption>
        </div>
        </div>';
```

but it applied when it was done this way:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="wow fadeInLeft animated portfolio-item" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="0ms" style="box-shadow: 0px 10px 12px grey; width:80%">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="booksCovers/" class="img-responsive" alt="this is a title" style="width : 450px ; height :320px; " />
            <div class="mybooks-overlay">
              <div class="desc">
                <div class="description">
</div>             
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <figcaption>



            <button class="myButtone">
              <div class="insider"> </div>
              20. 00$
            </button>


            <div class="heart"></div>

          </figcaption>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is the output html what you are expecting and in the right location? You should also just make 1 query for the data not 2. `$bookInfo = "SELECT cover, description from books where bookno = '$temp';";`

Comment: @Second2None both files used are .php. I tried putting same html code as is without being surrounded by echo' ' and style worked just fine.

Comment: You need to check what your PHP is outputting, check your pages source code and make sure you are getting the desired results. PHP is server side code, its run first.

Comment: @Second2None is it the reason for style not loading? because PHP creates the elements before the style is loaded?

Comment: No, its more than likely being echoed in the wrong area or you have problems in your HTML. Edit your post to show how you include your PHP files.